# Integrating sea level curve data in a bathymetric grid

Tags: arcmap, terrain, bathymetry, sea-level-rise

I am attempting to apply these data recording where sea-level was in the Gulf of Mexico (in meters below mean sea level) over the past 20,000 calendar years at a 500-year resolution in ArcMap:

[image]

What would be the best way to integrate this into a bathymetric raster so that the resulting map could be visualized with the various "shorelines" over time? Ideally, a .GRD file could be exported with an added column to the existing x, y, and z data, which may be tricky for visualization because it's the vertical shoreline progression is not always in a constant direction with time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach that could be used:

1. Acquire numerical raster of present day sea level for your region of
   interest.  see for example [Gebco](https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gridded_bathymetry_data/)
2. Using [map algebra](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/map-algebra/a-quick-tour-of-using-map-algebra.htm) create a new raster for each epoch by *subtracting* the SL correction value.  E.g.:

   `outRas = Raster("gebco") - (-119)`

Gebco is an MSL-relevant terrain and depth model (depths are negative down). This will re-base all *elevations* (whether land or sea) to mean sea level at that epoch.

You could then symbolize each raster identically to show shoreline change.